# Getting the shape attribute of an area with jQuery in IE6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, shapes, area

I'm currently using the qTip2 Plugin for jQuery - with the IE6 & ImageMap Additions of qTip2 - to display a tooltip with html content when an area is hovered.

With Firefox, Chrome or IE8+ there is no problem, but in IE6 & IE7 the tooltip won't show up. I tried my best to debug the problem and to me it seems that the core of the problem is that jQuery can't determine the shape of the area which leads to wrong calculations of width, height and positioning.
The code fragment of qTip: `shape = (area.attr('shape') || 'rect')`

This always returns `rect`, so further down the code four coords area expected, but in case of a circle only three are present which results in a `NaN` value for the height and so on.
Did anyone experience this problem? Are there known solutions? I couldn't find any while searching the web yesterday, maybe I was too frustrated with IE6 and searched the wrong terms.

The IE6 Addition of qTip2 seems to only enhance the tooltip itself, and changes nothing of the ImageMap Addition.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution myself. I simply fetch the DOM-Object and extract the shape from there, that works in IE6 as well.

`shape = (area.attr('shape') || area[0].shape || 'rect')`

Comment: I'm to lazy to test that now, sorry, but my first guess after reading the jQuery documentation for prop() would be no.